# Do solids affect equlibrium?

Tags: equilibrium

After doing a calculation on $K_{C}$, I was told that solids do not affect the calculation.

This is confusing me. Is there a specific reason why solids do not affect the equilibrium shift?

Thanks.

Comment: Why, they do, only in a binary manner. Liquids and gases may have different concentrations or activities (10, 2, 1, 0.1, 0.005...), but a solid is either there (1) or not there (0).

Comment: Loose generalizations make me nervous. Let's be more specific and note that for example the $\mathrm{K}_{\mathrm{sp}}$ doesn't depend on how much of the solid phase is present. If however you're using activated charcoal to absorb something from solution, then how much charcoal you add does change the equilibrium.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - while in 'pure' chemistry you may be correct, the rather trivial extension to materials science and the thermodynamics of solids (alloys, etc.) suggests otherwise. There, of course, one has varying concentrations in the solid state, and have to apply the correct thermodynamics to obtain the equilibrium concentrations leading to the correct phase diagrams.

Comment: @Jon_Custer - That was why I was trying to bound the remark. If you want to talk about the solid phase in a liquid metal mixture using a phase diagram then equilibrium has other ramifications.